# SQL group by and where clause in PERL

Tags: perl

Can't execute this code...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $qstr = "select id as 'id', 
                   status as 'status', 
                   $subject.title as 'title', 
                   $subject.component as 'component', 
                   $subject.submitted_date as 'submitted_date', 
                   $subject.closed_date as 'closed_date' 
             where ($subject.title like 'PM_Production' 
               and ($subject.status = 'complete' 
                 OR $subject.status = 'rejected'))";
my $results = &search($api, $tenant, $subject, $qstr); 

foreach my $singleRow (@$results) {
    my $title =$singleRow->{'title'};
    my $component = $singleRow->{'component'};
    my $sub_date = $singleRow->{'submitted_date'};
    my $closed_date = $singleRow->{'closed_date'};

    print "$title, $component, $sub_date, $closed_date\n";
}
```

having error as below;

```
Syntax Error

 -- Error 15: Invalid Operator Found: "like"
```

Expected output: would like to filter all of the data in which title contains "PM_Pro"

P.S. Data title example:

```
 Title             Ticket Submitted_date      Ticket closed_date
 PM_Pro_test1      2017-05-11 12:47:08.2      2017-05-26 07:00:16.0
 PM_Pro_test2      2017-05-11 13:23:10.96     2017-05-27 22:01:02.0
 Testi_PM_Pro      2017-05-11 13:23:02.483    2017-05-24 08:10:20.0
 Testii_PM_Pro     2017-05-11 13:28:35.247    2017-05-24 08:12:33.0
```

Comment: i recognize this code. this isnt really sql. what you should use here instead of `like` is `CONTAINS`

Comment: This is no valid `SQL`. You are not stating from which tables you want to select. And you do not show how you are connecting to the db server. You give no detail what kind of database you are trying to connect to. Without more details there will likely be no good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your column aliases should be quoted by double quotes or be unquoted.

Secondly, there is no FROM clause (something like "FROM $subject").

Thirdly, looks like you need = operator instead of LIKE.

Looks like You want to write something like

```
my $qstr = "select $subject.id as id, $subject.status as status, $subject.title as title, $subject.component as component, $subject.submitted_date as submitted_date, $subject.closed_date as closed_date from $subject where ($subject.title = 'PM_Production' and ($subject.status = 'complete' OR $subject.status = 'rejected'))";
```